# INSTALL "[AMD/ATI] Tonga XT GL [FirePro S7150]" Graphic Card on a VMu (Centos 6.9) running on XenServer 7.4

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, centos-6.9

Just start using XenServer. Doing some experiment for my company. Installed XenServer 7.4 on a Box and created a Centos 6.9 VMU. Using XenCenter.

Got to the point when I can run the virtual operating system but when I try to use the "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga XT GL [FirePro S7150]" graphic card with the command:

xe vgpu-create vm-uuid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx gpu-group-uuid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

I receive the following error message:

> The use of this feature is restricted.

I have also tried to install the graphic interface (Xen-Center) using a licensed Xen-Server to enable the AMD card using the Tools->Install Update: downloaded and selected the mxgpu-1.0.5.amd.iso to enable the Graphic card but I cannot complete the process as I receive the error message:

> The attempt to create a VDI failed

I am running out of option. The CentOS is running but I cannot use the machine AMD graphic card. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running the VM with the virtual disk stored on the same Local Storage repository located on that card's host, and removed from any pools. This is the default configuration, but I'd thought I'd mention these tips in case you have this box somehow mixed in a heterogenous pool. If the machine is part of a pool, make sure that you are not selecting the video adapter to passthrough to the VM of another host's adapter.